# Why does regex show a match even when one of the characters isn't there in the string?

Tags: regex, shell, sed

when running this:

```
echo "abcd/fgh/ijkl" | sed 's|[^/]*/\(.*\)|\1|'
```

the output as expected is

```
fgh/ijkl
```

but when running this:

```
echo "abcd" | sed 's|[^/]*/\(.*\)|\1|'
```

The output is

```
abcd
```

instead of the expected null string. Why does this match even when there is no `/` in the string. Is this due to the greediness of the regex. How do I make it work correctly?

Comment: This is because `abcd` does not match the `[^/]*/\(.*\)` regex, so that no replacement is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't match.  The substition in `sed` will only run on matching lines, and `sed` by default prints all lines.  Try

```
echo "abcd" | sed -n 's|[^/]*/\(.*\)|\1|p'
```

The `-n` flag means "No output by default" and the `p` modifier at the end will print whenever it does a substitution.

Comment: [Speedy Delivery](http://pbskids.org/rogers/R_house/speedydelivery/speedy.html) to you!

Comment: just for info: null string is not empty string. In this sample it will produce an empty string (return a string with nothing inside) as expected but on multiline the line is not printed (null string) at all if no substitution occur for the current line and this is not always the expected result (less output number of line than entry)